# how to remove the side blue line from my site

Tags: css, wordpress

[image: screenshot]

how to remove the blue line from the website which has been created on WordPress plz help after using smart slider plugin this is happening

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. And please use only relevant tags. There is **no** reason at all to tag this question with java!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to give a proper solution for your query is when we get your site url. The blue line may be "box-shadow", "Outline", "Border" or Background of an element. However we need physically visit to your site. So, provide the url.

Comment: thanks already solved